# Jquery Append is not working in expected order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Happy new year.I am trying to create pagination links..So basically my code is big so i created below code for easy understanding.

```
<div id = "test"></div>

func1();

function func1() {
    $("#test").append("<nav><ul class='pagination pagination-lg'>");
    func3();
    $("#test").append("</ul></nav>");
}

function func2() {

$("#test").append("<li>data</li>"); 
}

function func3() {
func2();
}
```

I expect the result to be like

```
<nav><ul class="pagination pagination-lg"><li>data</li></ul></nav>
```

But the output is

```
<nav><ul class="pagination pagination-lg"></ul></nav><li>data</li>
```

Why is this happening ?eventhough i call function before appending the `</ul></li>`

P.s Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s6d5wytf/

Comment: Why do you make it so complicated!?

Comment: Look at how append works: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: because my orginal function is like this http://jsfiddle.net/885SQ/ , what do u expect me to do

Comment: That code looks like it needs some serious refactoring and jQuery is just the right tool to do it. If you read up on the link I posted above, you will become familiar with this functionality

Comment: I know Even if I update the function with appends ! It will be still malformed..benjamin answer is correct

Comment: `Try this:

    <div id = "test"></div>
    
    func1();
    
    function func1() {
        $("#test").append("<nav><ul class='pagination pagination-lg'>");
        $(".pagination.pagination-lg").html($('<li>data</li>'));
    }`

Comment: Actually I believe this is a different phenomena than the marked duplicate since in this case `ul` close tags are _optional_ and appending them with `.innerHTML` would produce the same result and in that question jQuery is the one completing the tags which would otherwise not happen. Solution is the same though.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEVaaE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you append malformed HTML the browser will do its best to turn it into well formed HTML so when you do:

```
    $("#test").append("<nav><ul class='pagination pagination-lg'>");
```

The browser sees it has an opened `<ul>` tag without a `</ul>` and will assume you're done with it - especially since a little known fact is `</ul>` tags are implicit and can be inferred by the browser.

So - what you're conceptually appending in the first go is:

```
    $("#test").append("<nav><ul class='pagination pagination-lg'></ul></nav>");
```

What you want to be doing is either use a temporary element you construct and append to or chain strings. Here is an example of the first approach

```
function func1() {
    var menu = $("<nav></nav>"); // create but not add anywhere
    menu.append("<ul class='pagination pagination-lg'></ul"); // add ul
    func3(menu);
    $("#test").append(menu);
}

function func2(menu) {
    menu.find("ul").append("<li>data</li>"); 
}
```

This also has the added benefit of querying the actual document only once which is faster although if you only do it 3 times it's negligible.